# How to get the word before the character reach 20 character if the text is too long

Tags: php, while-loop, substr

```
<?php 
$conn1 = new MySqli('localhost','root','','test');

$data = "Hubert Blaine Wolfeschlegel Steinhausenbergerdorff Sr.";
$namelength = strlen($data);
$a = 20;
echo"<br>".$data;

#first name 
    $a = 20;

    if($namelength <= $a)
    {
      echo"<br>".$firstname =  substr($data ,0,$a);
    }
    else if ($namelength >= $a)
    {
      $a = 20;
      while(substr($data ,$a, 1) != " ")
      {
        $a-=1;
      }
      echo"<br>".$firstname =  substr($data ,0, $a);
    }
#second name
    $b = ($a + 20);
    if( $namelength <= $b)
    {
      echo"<br>".$secname =  substr($data ,($a),$namelength);

    }
    else if($namelength >= $b)
    { 
      $b = 40;
      while(substr($data ,$b, 1) != " ")
      {
        $b-=1;
      }
      $secname =  substr($data ,21, $b);
      $secname=trim($secname);
      echo"<br>".$secname;


    }
#third name
    $c = ($b + 20);
    if ( $namelength <=$c) {
      echo"<br>".$thirdname =  substr($data ,($c+1),$namelength);
    }
    else if($namelength >= $c)
    { 
      $c = 60;
      while(substr($data ,$c, 1) != " ")
      {
        $c -=1;
      }
      echo"<br>".$thirdname =  substr($data ,41, $c);
    }
    
?>
```

this is what i want to do: if the name length over 60 characters break the name into 3 lines with each line 20 characters

I want to for the second name to read before the spaces
and also the third name to read the word before spaces even though it count as 20 character
i don't want it to break the words

Comment: sorry, can you simplify, what is the input, what is your code output, what is your expected result?

Comment: If your input is separated by spaces, you can split (explode) by spaces to an array. Loop the array, keep a count, and when over 20, revert to last (previous index) iteration.

Comment: A better question would be: why do you want to do this?

Comment: i want to seperate the name so can insert into database for id card appllication paper

Comment: So why is 20 the char max?

Comment: it suppose to cut it each time when char reach 20

Comment: i want to cut into 20 char three times and if more than 60 char stop

Comment: Ok. explode() the input, loop thru the array and cut each string to 20 char.

Comment: can you show the code to do this i'm new to programming cause still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $data  = "Hubert Blaine Wolfeschlegel Steinhausenbergerdorff Sr.";

    // $lines = explode("/ +/", $data);
    // $clean = array_map("trim",$lines);
    // $output = array_filter(array_unique($clean));
    // print_r($output);
    $data       = trim($data);
    echo"  Length : ".$namelength = strlen($data);
   
   $a =  20;
   if ($namelength < $a)
   {
     echo"<br>nama 1 : ".$nama1 = substr($data,0,$a);
   }
   else if ($namelength >= $a)
   {
    while(substr($data,$a,1) != " ")
    { $a -= 1;}
   
    echo"<br>nama 1 : ".$nama1 = substr($data,0,$a);
   }
      $b = $a + 20;
      if ($b > $namelength)
      {
        echo"<br>nama 2 : ".$nama2 = substr($data,($a+1),$namelength);
      }
      else
      {
        while(substr($data,$b,1) != " ")
        { $b -= 1;}
        $b = $b - $a;
        echo"<br>nama 2 : ".$nama2 = substr($data,($a+1),$b);
      }

      $b = $b + $a;
      $c = $b + 20;
      if ($c > $namelength)
      {
        echo"<br>nama 3 : ".$nama3 = substr($data,($b+1),$namelength);
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<script> alert ("Hanya 60 aksara dipaparkan"); </script>';
        while(substr($data,$c,1) != " ")
        { $c -= 1;}
        $c = $c - $b;
        echo"<br>nama 3 : ".$nama3 = substr($data,($b+1),$c);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

based on GetSet's instruction above. try this below, change what you need to change, becasue I still dont understand what you want

```
$str = "Hubert Blaine Wolfeschlegel Steinhausenbergerdorff Sr.";
$res = "Hubert Blaine hlegel Steinhausenbergerdor rgerdorff Sr.";
$final_res = "";
print_r(explode(" ", $str));
$arr = explode(" ", $str);

$i = 0;
foreach($arr as &$value){
    echo("</br>val: ". $value);
    if($i == 1 && strlen($value) >= 20){ # 20 length?
        $value = substr($value, xxxx, zzzzz); # define your rule here, tbh I still dont get what your condition is
    }
    $final_res += $value;
}
```

Comment: this is what i want to do:
if the name length over 60 characters break the name into 3 lines with each line 20 characters

Comment: You should put your last comment (above) in your question @HazmanKun